# django 1.5 - How to use variables inside static tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I'm currently migrating all the static files references in my project to the new {% static %} tag that django 1.5 introduced, but I'm having a problem, in some places I use variables to get the content. With the new tag I can't, is there any way to solve this?

Current code:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/assets/flags/{{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }}.gif" alt="{% trans 'Language' %}" title="{% trans 'Language' %}" />
```

What it should be (this doesn't work):

```
<img src="{% static 'assets/flags/{{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }}.gif' %}" alt="{% trans 'Language' %}" title="{% trans 'Language' %}" />
```

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You should be able to concatenate strings with the [`add` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
{% with 'assets/flags/'|add:request.LANGUAGE_CODE|add:'.gif' as image_static %}
  {% static image_static %}
{% endwith %}
```

What you are trying to do doesn't work with the `static` template tag because it takes either a string or a variable only:

```
{% static "myapp/css/base.css" %}
{% static variable_with_path %}
{% static "myapp/css/base.css" as admin_base_css %}
{% static variable_with_path as varname %}
```

Comment: What if I want to put a variable{{var}} inside static tag?
with tag can only accept one var.

Answer (score 42):

For what it's worth, I think this is the easiest way:

```
<img src="{% static 'assets/flags/'|add:request.LANGUAGE_CODE|add:'.gif' %}" ... >
```

This is and old question and I'm not sure if this method could be done back then, But now, in Django 2.0 this seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I confirm that this method works in Django 2.0, and in my opinion, it is the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: Works for me, but the docs come with this warning: "Strings that can be coerced to integers will be summed, not concatenated"

Comment: Does not work with hashed file names (ManifestStaticfilesStorage ).

Comment: @run_the_race that is actually concerning. but since we know the first argument can't be an integer, in this case it should be safe.
Also, does hashed file names have "__str__" or "__add__" defined?

Comment: Being in Django 3.2.5 it's still the best way IMO.

Answer (score 32):

a cleaner way is to set the {% static %} as a variable from the beginning of the html so we can use it in any way we want.

```
{% load static %}
{% static "" as baseUrl %}
<img src="{{ baseUrl }}/img/{{p.id}}"></img>
```

Comment: This fails if you are using s3 storage with signed URLs, as the Storage backend if not invoked to prepare the URL for each file.

Comment: This looks very nice in a template but this is more of a hack than a clean way of using static.

Answer (score 25):

I got this to work by using an empty string for the static path and then using my variables in their own section, like this:

```
<a href= "{% static "" %}{{obj.a}}/{{obj.b}}/{{obj.c}}.gz" >Name</a>
```

Comment: this is super clever, but what @horbor said, you can simplify it even more! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-get_static_prefix

Comment: Rather than use an empty string, use `{% get_static_prefix %}`.

Comment: This doesn't URL encode any of the `{{obj.a}}` and so forth.

Answer (score 15):

@rounin, you can, at least, use

```
{% get_static_prefix %}
```

which will be loaded when you {% load static %}. It's just more natural then {% static '' %} :)

Comment: This won't work with things like ManifestStaticfilesStorage that changes `foo.js` into `foo.8c9a23d.js`

Answer (score 0):

Just put the variables outside of the tag:

```
src="{% static 'directory/' %}{{filename}}.{{fileextension}}"
```

Result: `"directory/filename.fileextension"`

Example Result: `"directory/bird.jpg"`