# Passing a computed argument to a django tag

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I'd like to compute the argument to a tag like this:

```
{% static /css/{{my_variable_here}}/rest/of/path.css %}
```

Is this possible? Or do I need to compute the string in the view?

Using django 1.4 (don't question it).

Comment: Is django templating a hard requirement? I ask because I know this is certainly possible with Mako, but I'm unsure about django's default template.

Comment: @That1Guy Yep, changes in the technology are not on the table.

Comment: Would the suggestions from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates) work, using the `add` filter?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Very cool! (Although kind of an abuse)

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was a bit of a hack too, but it's not an easy problem to solve elegantly. You can't create a tag, because you want to use `static`, and a custom filter wouldn't be much cleaner than `add` (if at all). Using `STATICFILES_DIRS`, or the static files loaders, might be an option, but I've never looked into that so I have no idea.

Comment: `Using django 1.4 (don't question it)` - hah I am still supporting 1.3

Answer (score 0):

I recall having read that putting a template variable inside a tab is a definite no-go. You could perhaps write a custom tag that took your my_variable_here value, just as the built-in "url" tag takes arguments.

But early on I found stackoverflow suggestions about how to resolve some of the usual static files issues that led me to do things this way:

```
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The drawback is of course that with every view that needs to use the static file I have to do something like this:

```
return render_to_response('some_page.html', {'STATIC_URL': settings.STATIC_URL})
```

And "settings" is the project settings.py file and it must be imported.

So obviously with that scheme you could add your {{my_variable_here}} variable as you please.

Edit of 9/6/14 started here (I'm having to respond to Marcin's first comment here so as to show some code). @Marcin, I don't know for sure what you mean by portability across environments. Under the simple circumstances of going from a Linux development machine to a Linux shared-hosting production server I'm having no such problems. I can simply download a copy of the production server setup and put it in any directory of the development server and, after launching the virtualenv, run the project on the development server--- after changing one boolean in the settings.py file:

```
IS_PRODUCTION = False
DEBUG = True
if IS_PRODUCTION: DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PUBLIC_HTML = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
if IS_PRODUCTION:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_sendmail_backend.backends.EmailBackend'
else:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
if IS_PRODUCTION: ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ u'www.mydomainname.com', u'mydomainname.com']
if not DEBUG and not IS_PRODUCTION: ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ u'127.0.0.1', u'127.0.0.1:8000' ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/static/')
if IS_PRODUCTION:
    STATIC_URL = 'http://www.mydomainname.com/rb/public/static/'
else:
    STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PUBLIC_HTML, 'dygraph'),
    os.path.join(PUBLIC_HTML, 'ico'),
    os.path.join(PUBLIC_HTML, 'jquery'),
    .... etc.
)
```

So with that approach I specify directories from which collectstatic is to collect files into public/static. That is the extent to which I care to rely on Django's automated static file arrangements. Note that I only have to change the boolean value in the first line to go from development to production server (provided that I leave the STATICFILES_DIRS in the same directory relationship to the project root folder).

But... I have [an answer that will probably be more to your liking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag). That is, I've found that your question was previously answered on another stackoverflow page. Note that @rounin on Mar 13th pointed to the django docs but I'll provide [the exact docs for your miserable version 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-get_static_prefix).

I'll be looking into changing my own code so as to make use of {% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %} instead of transmitting STATIC_PREFIX in a response. I submit that this covers the topic.

Comment: Thanks for this, but the problem I'm solving is that this method is broken - it's not reliably portable across environments. Also, you can configure Django to always supply the static root in the environment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/

Comment: @Marcin, as far as I know STATIC_ROOT is just the directory into which collectstatic collects; STATIC_URL is a URL (unless you're on the development server in which case you could call it a directory). Anyway, I just posted an edit that cites a previous stackoverflow thread--- I just found it--- that may be to your liking. Here's the related django docs reference [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-get_static_prefix]. When all's said and done that approach appears to be what I had suggested (`STATIC_PREFIX` appears to be the same as `STATIC_URL`).

Comment: See this article for the problem with this approach: http://staticfiles.productiondjango.com/blog/stop-using-static-url-in-templates/

Comment: If you go to the linked-to docs in my previous comment, take the ] off of the end of the URL in the location box to get to `get_static_prefix`. Then, right above it, see that there's a chance to replace my `load static` with `load static from staticfiles`. I'm talking about the "Note" insert. I can't find an example in the docs of `get_static_prefix` following a load from `staticfiles', but it looks as though it would work anyway. See also `user_stylesheet` passed as a variable, without {{}}, just above the Note box. My substituting `STATIC_URL` for `STATIC_PREFIX` was harmless, I think.

Comment: Strike the last sentence of the comment above please (I was stupidly talking about my own code, not about what I wrote above) @Marcin, should this fail maybe you need to rewrite the static tag so as to take your values and register it as a custom tag (as I had first suggested).

Comment: I have found another approach [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates].