# Use Django Template Tags in img src

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to use the Django template tags to bring up specific images that correlate with each choice, however it does not seem to work, just return a broken image. Here is my relevant html:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{% static "images/risk_graphics/{{ input.choice }}.jpg" %}"/>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't use variables inside the `static` tag.

Comment: @Leistungsabfall are you sure about that? ...

Comment: try `{% static "images/risk_graphics/"+ input.choice+".jpg" %}` , you cannot nest `{{}}` inside of `{% %}`

Comment: @JoranBeasley 100% sure. Sadly concatenation doesn't work either. But there are workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag

Comment: allright thanks :) I was going to suggest `{% with %}` really though just changing to jinja backend might solve alot of OP's pain ... thank you I learned somethng new today :P ...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the concentration does not work, I will try the "add" filter.

Answer (score 1):

Just set a variable on the context containing the path to the file in question. You can reference variables in the `static` template tag (here named `special_image_path`):

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{% static special_image_path %}"/>
```

See the second example here [in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag)