# Doesn't show image in browser using variables inside static tag

Tags: django, concatenation, django-staticfiles

I need to concatenate two strings inside a static tag, i checked previous question about how to concatenate strings in django template and i found **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16656232/6796652)**, but when i used that solution, the broser (Firefox) doesn't show the image.

Details:
This is my code, assume that the value of user.if is 1:

`{% with "images/my_twitter_wordcloud_"|add:user.id|add:".png" as image_static %}
<center>
<img src="{% static 'image_static' %}" width="650" height="350" style="margin-left: 10%;"/>
</center>
{% endwith %}`

When i ckecked the inspector in the browser, it showed the image like this:

```
<img src="/static/image_static" style="margin-left: 10%;" height="350" width="650">
```

I think that it should be:

```
    <img src="/static/images/my_twitter_wordcloud_"|add:user.id|add:"png" style="margin-left: 10%;" height="350" width="650">
```

I checked the django documentation about add reference, and i tried using "" and "" after add, but It seems like django doesn't interpretate the variable, what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.
PD: i'm apologyze for my English.

Edit:
Doing what @Selcuk said, the inspector show me this:

`<img src="/static/.png" style="margin-left: 10%;" height="350" width="650">`

Is strange, even if i use '' instead of "", so i don't understand what is wrong, if i put this (where the value of user.id is 1):

`<center><img src="{% static 'images/my_twitter_wordcloud_1.png' %}"`

It show the image correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `image_static` and use the variable name. That is, replace the following:

```
{% static 'image_static' %}
```

with this

```
{% static image_static %}
```

As a side note, you should also include a dot (`.`) before the image extension (`png`).

Answer (score 0):

for future people who will come here.

avarage_rating can hold any single value from this list [0,1,2,3,4,5] including decimals.

so use a single variable as a value and the loading dynamic image is below.

{{avarage_rating | first }} == first digit and .svg is appended to it.
here **s** is the name of the image initial.

```
<code><img src="{% static 'img/s'%}{{avarage_rating | first }}.svg"><span>{{avarage_rating}}</span></code>
```