# How to use a variable in a Django template between {% %}

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, django-templates

It's my first approach to **matplotlib**.

I have been trying for a while to print my plots in a template. I know how if I do this for just one image, but now I'm trying to modify it and call different images.

**I got this and it works perfectly:**

```
 <img src="{% static "/consulta/imagenes/rosavientos.png" %}">
```

**But I'm trying to use this path: *"/consulta/imagenes/rosavientos.png"* like this:**

```
  <img src="{% static {{ my_path }} %}">
```

**But ID or literal expected after *static*.**

Is it possible to do this in any way?

**PS: I also tried this:**

In my view:

```
ruta_estatica = "<img src = \"{% static '/consulta/imagenes/" + nombre_png + ".png' %}\">"
```

In the template:

```
  {% autoescape off %}{{ respuesta3 }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag

Comment: Thank you for the link @neverwalkaloner. 

My Django version is newer (1.11), but that solution still works. I had not seen that question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `with` tag to create a variable and use that in the `static` tag

```
 {% with '/consulta/imagenes/'|add:nombre_png|add:'.png' as image %}
   <img src="{% static image %}"/>
 {% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I had the same problem and the provided answer by @Brobin was a little bit confusing to me I'll try to clarify it a little bit more.

Considering you have the variable:
`{{ my_path }}`

and you want to use it inside the function:
`<img src="{% static 'some path here...' %}">`

you can directly input the variable inside the `static` function without the `{{ }}` as follows:
`<img src="{% static my_path %}">`

Now lets assume you want more complex processing like having an 'item' from the 'my_path' as if it was a list of paths and also include some other text to that as a path or file type, you'll have to use the `with` function:

```
{% with final_path='MainSite/videos/My_Sample_Video_'|add:my_path.0|add:'.mp4' %}
    <source src="{% static final_path %}" type="video/mp4">
{% endwith %}
```

Hope that helps.