# How to pass a key of dictionary into anchor tag in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this following dictionary:

```
results[calendar.month_name[date_cursor.month]] =  [e,z]
```

My url is:

```
    url(r'^company/(?P<pk>\d+)/purchasedelete/(?P<month>\d+)/date/(?P<pk3>\d+)/$',views.purchase_register_datewise,name='purchase_datewise'),
```

My view:

```
def purchase_register_datewise(request,month,pk,pk3):
    company_details = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=pk)
    selectdatefield_details = get_object_or_404(Selectdatefield, pk=pk3)

    result = Purchase.objects.filter(Company=company_details.pk, date__month=month, date__gte=selectdatefield_details.Start_Date, date__lt=selectdatefield_details.End_Date)



    context = {

        'company_details'             : company_details,
        'selectdatefield_details'     : selectdatefield_details,
        'result'                      : result, 

    }

    return render(request, 'stockkeeping/purchase/Purchase_Register_Datewise.html', context)
```

In my template:

```
        {% for key, value in data %}
          <tr>
            <td><center><a href="{% url 'stockkeeping:purchase_datewise' pk=company_details.pk month={{ key }} pk3=selectdatefield_details.pk %}"></a>{{ key }}</center></td>

            {% if value.0 == 0 %}
              <th><center></center></th>
            {% else %}
              <td><center>{{ value.0 }}</center></td>
            {% endif %}

            <th><center></center></th>
            {% if value.1 == 0 %}
              <th><center></center></th>
            {% else %}
              <td><center>{{ value.1 }} Dr</center></td>
            {% endif %}
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

When I try to do `month={{ key }}`

It throws me a error like this `Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'`

Can anyone tell me how to pass the value of key in my template.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django 1.5 - How to use variables inside static tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag)

Comment: I have not found my solution there @IvanStarostin

Comment: Try month=key? You can't use template tags inside template tags.

Comment: You use `month=key` just as you did `pk3=selectedatefield_details.pk`.

Comment: Yeah the value comes after doing `month=key` but its not rendering me to the desired page,. Can you tell me why?I have updated my question

Comment: Have you manually checked the url? Is the `month` parameter actually causing the problem?

Comment: Yeah I get it now the `month` parameter is taking integer value of months when I remove `calendar.month_name[date_cursor.month]` to only `date_cursor.month` it works fine... Thank you everyone for the help.