# Sending an object as context and want to use it as static file name

Tags: django, django-views

I have a product model that has an image_name property.

```
image_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I would like to store inside a static image name such as "super_product.jpg" for example.

In my product view, I am sending the full object as context.

```
def product_detail_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    context = {
        'object': obj
    }
    return render(request, "products/product_detail.html", context)
```

The problem is in my html. I tried to do this way:

```
<img src="{% static {{ object.image_name }} %}" />
```

But it doesn't seem possible to use static and object property this way.

Does anyone know a way to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django 1.5 - How to use variables inside static tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag)

Answer (score 0):

In **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In **template** file:

```
<img src="{% static object.image_name %}" />
```

You wrote `<img src="{% static {{ object.image_name }} %}" />` `{% static 'path.image'%}` that is the convention so you do not need to add extra curly braces to show the image name.

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot!