# How to use id as file name in django base template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a base file in my django template and it has an image in my nav that of the employee:

```
<img src="{% static 'assets/dist/img/employee/'1.jpg' %}" class="rounded-circle" width="50" height="50" alt="user"></a>
```

And i need that **1.jpg** received **{{user.employee.id}}**
but i can't concat .. i try this but not work:

```
<img src="{% static 'assets/dist/img/employee/'|add:{{user.employee.id}}|add:'.jpg' %}" class="rounded-circle" width="50"
                                     height="50" alt="user"></a>
```

Comment: Depends on version of Django see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag

Comment: @Ben, tks, but i use s3 storage, i'll have problems??

Comment: In that case you probably just want to pass the image url through the view context, for ex: in view `context["employee"] = employee` and in html `<img src="{{ employee.image.url }}" >`

Comment: @Ben, this is my problem, this a base template, don't have view...