# How to add two URLs together in {% static %} tag in django

Tags: html, django, django-staticfiles

Does somebody know if it is possible to add the following two strings together, so that django reads it as one url?

Django template:

```
src="{% static 'post_it/media/post_images/' + '{{ post.image_name }}' %}"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show `post` model definition. And settings related to static and media files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django 1.5 - How to use variables inside static tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag)