# Django move variable in template for <img src="">

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a variable contain url my file image

```
m='media/abc2021x07x13/ch00002_01000000025099767142400187070_29H75756.jpg'
return render(request, 'new_template/view_image.html',{'form1': m})
```

and move to template to display

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static '{{form1}}' %}"
 width="1440" height="948" /
```

it can't display but when i try this, it can display

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'media/abc2021x07x13/ch00002_01000000025099767142400187070_29H75756.jpg' %}"
 width="1440" height="948" />
```

Comment: Does `{% static form1 %}` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need quotes and keys:

```
<img src="{% static form1 %}" width="1440" height="948" />
```

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag