# How can I use a Django variable in my html img tag?

Tags: python, django, syntax

I need to use a variable for creation of a url for the img html tag.
I use python - Django.

Here's a hardcoded example of what I need:

```
<img src="{% static '/images/1.png' %}" alt="">
```

And here's what I tried (but failed):

I want to use x.id variable (currently it equals 1), in my url. Something like this:

```
<img src="{% static '/images/'{{ x.id }}'.png' %}" alt="">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The philosophy of django template is to put logic in the view not in the template.

You should create the value `"/images/{x.id}.png"` directly in the view.

Comment: The answer you need may be found there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag